# mq_notify in Cygwin doesn't trigger

Tags: c, cygwin, posix, ipc, message-queue

I'm using POSIX queues (mqueue) to communicate between threads.

The problem I have is that mq_notify doesn't function as expected in my unit tests on Cygwin. It never triggers even though the msg queue goes from empty to 1 msg.

I made an example that functions on Linux. When the same code is compiled in Cygwin, it doesn't work.

Could it be that Cygwin doesn't support mq_notify or is it a bug in Cygwin?

**notification example:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include "mqueue.h"

static void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

static void handleMessage(union sigval sv)
{
    ssize_t n;
    char buf[256];
    struct mq_attr mqAttr = {0};
    mqd_t mqdes = *((mqd_t *) sv.sival_ptr);

    printf("handleMessage\n");
    if (mq_getattr(mqdes, &mqAttr) == -1) {
        error("mq_getattr");
    }

    printf("handleMessage msgs:%i\n", mqAttr.mq_curmsgs);

    while (mqAttr.mq_curmsgs > 0) {
        n = mq_receive(mqdes, buf, mqAttr.mq_msgsize, NULL);

        if (n == -1) {
            error("mq_receive");
            break;

        } else {
            printf("Read %ld bytes from MQ\n", (long) n);
        }

        if (mq_getattr(mqdes, &mqAttr) == -1) {
            error("mq_getattr");
        }
    }

    {
        struct sigevent sev;
        sev.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD;
        sev.sigev_notify_function = handleMessage;
        sev.sigev_notify_attributes = NULL;
        sev.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &mqdes; 

        if (mq_notify(mqdes, &sev) == -1) {
           error("mq_notify");
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{       
    struct mq_attr      mqAttr;
    mqd_t queue;
    struct sigevent sev;

    mqAttr.mq_maxmsg = 10;
    mqAttr.mq_msgsize = 50;
    mqAttr.mq_flags = 0;

    queue = mq_open(argv[1], O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666, NULL);

    if(queue == -1) {
        error("mq_open");
    }
    sev.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD;
    sev.sigev_notify_function = handleMessage;
    sev.sigev_notify_attributes = NULL;
    sev.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &queue;  

    if (mq_notify(queue, &sev) == -1) {
       error("mq_notify");
    }

    while(1) {
    /* Pass data to mq */
        char buffer[20];
        static int cnt = 0;

        sprintf(buffer, "mq_send %i", ++cnt);
        printf("%s q:%X\n", buffer, queue);
        if (mq_send(queue, (char*)buffer, (strlen(buffer) + 1), 100) != 0) {
            error("mq_send");
        }
        usleep(1000000); // sleep 1s
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Got similar issue with example code from [http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/index.html](TLPI). Did you find your way out?
@Duck the example code  in TLPI properly uses sv.sival_ptr to re-register the notification. So root cause is elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have Cygwin set up so I couldn't confirm what you are seeing.  However this error jumps out: in `handleMessage()` you reset the notification and use this line:

```
sev.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &mqdes;
```

This isn't going to work because mqdes is a variable on the current stack.  Once the queue is empty this thread (and its associated stack) is going to disappear.  When that happens mqdes can be pointing at anything in memory when the next thread is started.  A simple fix is to just use the pointer passed into the current thread.

```
sev.sigev_value.sival_ptr = sv.sival_ptr;
```

On your main question, are you sure you delete the queue before you make subsequent runs in the program?  If the queue isn't empty a new thread will never start.

Answer (score 0):

As @Duck stated, your queue is probably **not** empty. That was my case when I faced similar issue today. You need to empty the queue with multiple calls to `mq_receive` to get notified in the future. In your `main()`, I suggest following code after your `mq_notify`:

```
mqd_t queue_nb; /* non-blocking queue */

[...]

if (mq_notify(queue, &sev) == -1) {
   error("mq_notify");
}

queue_nb = mq_open(argv[1], O_NONBLOCK | O_RDONLY, 0666, NULL);
if(queue == -1) {
    error("mq_open");
}

if (mq_getattr(mqdes, &mqAttr) == -1) {
    error("mq_getattr");
}

n = 0;
while (n >= 0) {

    /* will not block */
    n = mq_receive(queue_nb, buf, mqAttr.mq_msgsize, NULL);
    if (n > 0) {
        printf("Read %ld bytes from MQ\n", (long) n);
    }
}
```